# Custom Spring Data JPA query using GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a custom Spring Data query that was defined like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.bram.entity.Project(v.projectName, v.author, v.creator, " +
        "MIN(v.receiveDate), MAX(v.lastUpdateDate), COUNT(v), SUM(v.numberTotal), SUM(v.numberTranslated)) " +
        "FROM Job v " +
        "WHERE v.company = :company " +
        "GROUP BY projectName",
    countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT projectName) FROM Job WHERE company = :company")
Page<Project> getProjectsForCompany(@Param("company") String company, Pageable pageable);
```

This works fine, but I would like to apply some sorting, namely from the projects descending starting with the most recently updated projects, MAX(v.lastUpdateDate). Normally this would just be like adding a simpe ORDER BY, but it doesn't seem to work. I cannot define the new object an AS-name and thus have no way of referring to the lastUpdateDate property of the Project class in the ORDER BY clause.

Does anyone happen to have an example?